# How can I calculate % change in values that I am getting in real time over google spreadsheet IMPORTHTML feature?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am importing some temperature values on a daily basis in google spreadsheet via `IMPORTHTML` function. I need to calculate the % change in values i.e. (current value - old value)/(current value).

The problem is as soon as the new values are imported, old values are lost and I am unable to automate the process.

Comment: Use a script to copy the imported data to some other sheet. You can automatically run such a script once a day.

Comment: It would probably be easier to do this in google-apps-script; use `UrlFetchApp` to retrieve the value and store it in the sheet using `appendRow()`, etc.